# Is it possible to look at code of a website to determine if they are using a CDN?

Tags: cdn

I am trying to determine how websites like hypebeast.com serves images/pages so quickly to Asia.  I know the site hypebeast.com has a dedicated server at Softlayer, but was wondering if they were using a CDN too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check it by using Firefox plugin YSlow or Google Page Speed

Comment: I have YSlow.  Where in YSlow does it show that the images are coming from a CDN?

Comment: YSlow shows the number of "static components that are not on CDN."  However, it does not let me know if the other static elements are using a CDN.

Comment: YSlow assign grade on "Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)" if it is grading website "A" on CDN it means website is using CDN :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  Happy New Year!